# build chromium android failed with comman "ninja -C out/Default chrome_public_apk"

Tags: android, chromium

I try to compile the chromium android in my Ubuntu.x64.14.04.3 according to the official website: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/android_build_instructions.md
But after I run "ninja -C out/Default chrome_public_apk", it goes to failure. with error message as follow:

```
xxxx@xxxx-VirtualBox:~/chromium/src$ ninja -C out/Default chrome_public_apk
ninja: Entering directory `out/Default'
[2/30589] ACTION //base:android_runtim...d/toolchain/android:android_clang_arm)
FAILED: gen/android_runtime_jni_headers/base/jni/Runtime_jni.h 
python ../../base/android/jni_generator/jni_generator.py --depfile gen/base/android_runtime_jni_headers__jni_Runtime.d --jar_file ../../third_party/android_tools/sdk/platforms/android-26/android.jar --input_file java/lang/Runtime.class --ptr_type=long --output_dir gen/android_runtime_jni_headers/base/jni --includes ../../../../../../base/android/jni_generator/jni_generator_helper.h --native_exports_optional
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../../base/android/jni_generator/jni_generator.py", line 1428, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "../../base/android/jni_generator/jni_generator.py", line 1421, in main
    GenerateJNIHeader(input_file, output_file, options)
  File "../../base/android/jni_generator/jni_generator.py", line 1326, in GenerateJNIHeader
    jni_from_javap = JNIFromJavaP.CreateFromClass(input_file, options)
  File "../../base/android/jni_generator/jni_generator.py", line 662, in CreateFromClass
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
[3/30589] ACTION //base:base_jni_heade...d/toolchain/android:android_clang_arm)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you miss some dependecies, you execute the

```
build/install-build-deps-android.sh ?
```

Comment: ./build/install-build-deps-android.sh: line 21: lsb_release: command not found

Answer (score 0):

You need to install JDK on your machine in order to build chromium properly.

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk-headless
```

Make sure these executables point to the same jdk version.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java  
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```